# QRCode' does not contain a definition for 'GetGraphic' and no accessible extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net

> 'QRCode' does not contain a definition for 'GetGraphic' and no
> accessible extension method 'GetGraphic' accepting a first argument of
> type 'QRCode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?)

I am tying to Generate QR Code in .Net 6 I am found an error, Tell me Where is my code wrong?

```
QRCodeGenerator qrCodeGenerator = new();
string data = "Name : " + employeeSalaryGetDetails.Name + "\n DOB : " + employeeSalaryGetDetails.DayofBirth.ToString() + "\n Email Address : " + employeeSalaryGetDetails.EmailId.ToString();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrCodeGenerator.CreateQrCode(data, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCoder = new();
qrCoder.Equals(qrCodeData);
Image rqCodeImage = qrCoder.GetGraphic(20);

var bytes = ImageToByteArray(rqCodeImage);
return File(bytes, "image/tmp");
```

Comment: have you made sure to include all off QRCode. I'm also curious why you use `qrCoder.Equals(qrCodeData)`. When I look on the QRCode github i find this exact example yet it doesnt use `.Equals`. It passes `qrCodeData` into the new `QRCode` directly like `QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);` Side note I recommend being consistent with the use of var/ typing out the type yourself, this will improve readability

Comment: I am trying to use QRCode qrCoder = new(qrCodeData);
 Image rqCodeImage = qrCoder.GetGraphic(20);
and found error "QRCode' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" and "QRCode' does not contain a definition for 'GetGraphic' and no accessible extension method 'GetGraphic' accepting a first argument of type 'QRCode' could be foun"

Comment: What library/nuget package this is?

Comment: i assume @frontend84dev is using https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/wiki/Advanced-usage---QR-Code-renderers

Comment: I am using this method .Net 5 so successfully generate QR Code but .Net 6 get the error

Comment: I am using QRCoder package @shahkalpesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the package is incomplete for .NET6.0 and up, in a new project when I implement `QRCoder` straight from nuget and Include the using `QRCoder`. Type `QRCode` doesn't exist. The github has some open issues involving this issue. Downgrading to nuget version 1.4.2 might fix your problem.

I have tried it and it works. It would look like this:

```
using QRCoder;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ClassLibrary1;
public class Class1
{
    public void CreateQR()
    {
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("The text which should be encoded.", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
        Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
    }
}
```

Note: This is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back to version 1.4.1 — the error should go away.